# Linux Mint - Just created launcher does not show on MATE desktop but is in ls listing

Tags: desktop, linux-mint

I created a launcher by right-clicking on my Desktop, filled in the fields and saved it. But it didn't appear on my Desktop. So I opened Caja and it did not show there either. So I opened a terminal and did `ll` and it is in the list. I counted all the files and indeed there was one more in the terminal list than there was in the Caja list.

So I did `mv xxx.desktop FolderA` in the terminal window and then opened FolderA with Caja and the file showed there. Then I drug its icon from the Caja window to my Desktop and then it was really there in all views.

This has happened twice tonight.

Is this a bug? What am I missing?

EDIT:
moved this question to [http://unix.stackexchange.com ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171222/linux-mint-just-created-launcher-does-not-show-on-mate-desktop-but-is-in-ls-li)

Comment: You should post that question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/!
Stackoverflow is for programming related Questions, or maybe you can get help in the official Linux Mint help IRC

Comment: Thank you. (Still finding my way.)

Comment: @SailorChibi I did now.

Comment: I found that a refresh (F5) causes the desktop to show the missing icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting F5 to refresh the Desktop causes the missing icon to appear.

I think this is still a bug though.